# Need help to sort processed mdb file in Python on Linux machine

Tags: python, database, linux, sorting, ms-access

I am trying to extract a table from .mdb file, then filter that table and spit out the result into short .csv file. So far I was able to extract the table needed and save it's content into .CSV. But I dont know how can I sort that data and extract the necessary rows I need. I guess I could save the the whole .csv and then reopen it, but it would take huge amount of space since I need to process about 2000 mdb files. I just want to extract certain rows.

```
Cycle Test_Time  Current    Voltage
1     7.80E-002 0.00E+000   1.21E-001
1     3.01E+001 0.00E+000   1.19E-001
1     6.02E+001 0.00E+000   1.17E-001
2     9.02E+001 0.00E+000   1.14E-001
2     1.20E+002 0.00E+000   1.11E-001
2     1.50E+002 0.00E+000   1.08E-001
2     1.80E+002 0.00E+000   1.05E-001
2     2.10E+002 0.00E+000   1.02E-001
3     2.40E+002 0.00E+000   9.93E-002
3     2.70E+002 0.00E+000   9.66E-002
3     3.00E+002 0.00E+000   9.38E-002
3     3.10E+002 4.00E-001   1.26E+000
```

For example, in the table above I want to do the following things:

1. Extract the last row of each cycle or, more advanced, sort the cycle by time and extract the row of the cycle with the latest time. As you can see, Last row does not always have the latest time due to our testing machine glitch, but usually does. But the bigger the number  the later the time.
2. Extract all the rows for last five cycles.
3. Extract all the rows from cycle 4 to cycle 30.

Here is my code:

```
import sys, subprocess, glob

mdbfiles = glob.glob('*.res')
for DATABASE in mdbfiles: 

    subprocess.call(["mdb-schema", DATABASE, "mysql"])

    table_names = subprocess.Popen(["mdb-tables", "-1", DATABASE],
                                   stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
    tables = table_names.splitlines()

    sys.stdout.flush()

    a=str('Channel_Normal_Table')

    for table in tables:
        if table != '' and table==a:

            filename = DATABASE.replace(".res","") + ".csv"
            file = open(filename, 'w')
            print("Dumping " + table)
            contents = subprocess.Popen(["mdb-export", DATABASE, table],
                                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]

            # I NEED TO PUT SOMETHING HERE TO SORT AND EXTRACT THE DATA I NEED


            file.write(contents)
            file.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be easier not to deal with a flat list of rows but convert it to a stucture which would allow to "query" the data easier first. Something like a list of dicts, where each dict represents a cycle:

```
cycles = {}

rows = contents.splitlines()  # split the `contents` text blob into individual lines

for row in rows[1:]:  # the first line in your question is a header - [1:] skips it
    row = rows.split()  # split each line by whitespace
    cycle = cycles.setdefault(row[0], {'id': row[0], 'rows': []}
    cycle['rows'].append({'cycle':row[0], 'test_time': row[1], 'current': row[2], ...})
```

Then you can sort them by test_time:

```
for key, cycle in cycles.items():
    cycles['rows'].sort(key=itemgetter('test_time'))
```

Then you can process your data. The last row of each cycle:

```
 for key, cycle in cycles.items():
    output_row(cycles['rows'][-1])
```

Rows of the last five cycles:

```
 for key, cycle in sorted(cycles.items())[:-5]:
    output_rows(cycles['rows'])
```

Extract rows from 4 to 30:

```
for idx in range(4, 31):
    cycle = cycles[str(idx)]
    output_rows(cycles['rows'])
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! It looks very good and quite clear but i am having difficulties putting that code into my original code.
I use:
 for row in contents:  instead of rows   -  am I doing it right? 
And getting an error: 
    cycle['rows'].append({'cycle':row[0], 'test_time': row[1], 'current': row[2]})            
IndexError: string index out of range

Sorry, I am so new to Python. Thanks again!

Comment: @Pasha: I've updated my answer to show how to split the command's output into individual lines and then to split each line into individual fields. You may need to tweak the code if there are empty lines in your output, headers etc.

Comment: Thanks again. I am tweaking the code but is getting errors so far. Will this code work for both Python 2 and 3?
I am not sure how these two lines work:
cycles['rows'].sort(key=itemgetter('test_time')) - getting an error with 'itemgetter'. What exactly is itemgetter?
&
output_row(cycles['rows'][-1]) - output_row was not previously defined
Sorry for noob questions.

Comment: @Pasha: the code above is not a complete working code, rather a pseudo-code which resembles Python. It would be tricky for me to write a complete working example which would work straight away. You need to import the itemgetter function: `from operator import itemgetter`. `output_row` is an imaginary function which somehow prints the row, writes it to file, saves to a database etc. You need to write it yourself.

Comment: With very little programming experience it's very hard for me to tweak the code. Anyway, thanks a lot for your help.